# "Экивоки"

Tags: этимология

А откуда взялось слово "экивоки", какое у него происхождение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово ЭКИВОКИ образовалось, вероятно, от слова ЭКВИВОКАЦИЯ французского происхождения.

Толковый словарь русского языка Д.Н.Ушакова:
ЭКИВОКИ (или екивоки), экивоков, ед. (редко) экивок, экивока, м. (***фр. йquivoque, ср. эквивокация***). Двусмысленности, двусмысленные намеки; увертки. Заламливая такие аллегории и екивоки, что, кажись, век бы не добился толку. Гоголь. Да нечто в нашем лесу можно такое дерево отыскать? - отвечал продавец уже без всяких экивоков. Г. Успенский.

ЭКВИВОКАЦИЯ — термин, введенный Боэцием и означающий ***равнозначность, равноголосие,*** ***двуосмысленность***. Связан с важнейшим христианским догматом творения мира по слову, где слово выполняет не только креативную, но и посредническую (между горним и дольним мирами) функцию.( http://dic.academic.ru)